# aligning images in tables

Tags: css, html

I need help aligning those three pictures horizontally with the text centered underneath each. I tried a few different css methods but it just aligned everything vertically

```html
<article>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <img src="images/index_cws.jpg" alt="Costal Water Scenes" height="350" width="350" />
      </th>
      <th>
        <img src="images/index_ss.jpg" alt="Street Scenes" height="350" width="350" />
      </th>
      <th>
        <img src="images/index_ws.jpg" alt="Window Sunrises" height="350" width="350" />
      </th>
      <tr/>
      <tr>
        <th>
          Costal Water Scenes
        </th>
        <th>
          Street Scenes
        </th>
        <th>
          Window Sunrises
        </th>
      </tr>
  </table>
</article>
```

Comment: It looks good to me, so please post a sketch showing the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can center the text under the images.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
 }
 
 .table td {
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 .table img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 16px;
 }
```

```html
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x40" alt="" aria-labelledby="i1" />
        <span id="i1">Costal Water Scenes</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x40" alt="" aria-labelledby="i2" />
        <span id="i2">Street Scenes</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x40" alt="" aria-labelledby="i3" />
        <span id="i3">Window Sunrises</span>
      </td>
    <tr/>
  </table>
```

A few things of note:
I combined the images and their title into a single table cell. I also wrapped each title in a span with a unique ID, so they could be appropriately assigned to the images via the `aria-labelledby` attribute.

I removed the alt text for the images, as they were redundant with the image titles. You should probably look at adding descriptive alt text to the images in place of the titles you previously had for them, or leave the alt text blank, as I have it, if the titles are the only important information that needs to be conveyed.

Hope this helps

Comment: all i needed was the css and it worked great, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you look for?

```css
article, td {
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200/66f" alt="Costal Water Scenes" height="350" width="350" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200/6f6" alt="Street Scenes" height="350" width="350" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200/f66" alt="Window Sunrises" height="350" width="350" />
      </td>
      <tr/>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Costal Water Scenes
        </td>
        <td>
          Street Scenes
        </td>
        <td>
          Window Sunrises
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</article>
```